# Asterisk 13.10.0 does not detect user input. DTMF not working

Tags: asterisk, sip, dtmf

I am trying to get user input from a phone dialpad but it is not working. Seems DTMF is not working

```
[general]
;context=unauthenticated
context=callingout
type=peer
;host=dynamic
allowguest=yes
 alwaysauthreject=yes
srvlookup=yes
 udpbindaddr=0.0.0.0
 tcpenable=no
;port=5038
 match_auth_username=yes
;alwaysauthreject=no
allowoverlap=no
allowtransfer=no
canreinvite=no
disallow=all
allow=g729
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw
;allow=gsm
;    allow=all
  directmedia=no
  ;nat=force_rport,comedia
   nat=yes
   externip=xx.xx.xx.xx
  ;localnet=192.168.0.3/255.255.0.0
   ;allow=speex
   dtmfmode=rfc2833
    qualify=yes


[callingout]
 srvlookup=no
 udpbindaddr=0.0.0.0
  type=friend
  host=xx.xx.xx.xx
     ;host=dynamic
 context=callingout
 canreinvite=no
 disallow=all
 allow=g729
 allow=ulaw
 allow=alaw
 dtmfmode=rfc2833
 extenip=xx.xx.xx.xx
 nat=yes
 qualify=yes

  [plan]
  srvlookup=no
   udpbindaddr=0.0.0.0
   type=friend
    host=xx.xx.xx.xx
   ;host=dynamic
   context=callingout
    canreinvite=no
    disallow=all
     allow=g729
     allow=ulaw
     allow=alaw
     dtmfmode=rfc2833
      extenip=xx.xx.xx.xx
       nat=yes
       qualify=yes


      [gateway-default] ; call is routed to this server IP
       type=peer
        insecure=invite,port
        nat=no
         directmedia=no
           host=xx.xx.xx.xx
           ;context=callingout
            disallow=all
            allow=g729
             allow=ulaw
         allow=alaw
         dtmfmode=rfc2833
```

I tried getting user input using Read statement in the dialplan

```
same => n,Read(pin_entered,/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/es/enter_PIN,4,i,1,5)
```

But I get the following output when I set sip and rtp debug on

```
    -- Accepting a maximum of 4 digits.
 Audio is at 17380
Adding codec g729 to SDP
Adding codec ulaw to SDP
Adding codec alaw to SDP

<--- Reliably Transmitting (NAT) to 46.19.209.14:5060 --->
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 46.19.209.14;branch=z9hG4bK6vxvLaBc;received=46.19.209.14;rport                                                                                        =5060
From: 16173730982 <sip:16173730982@46.19.209.14>;tag=3B8DECC2-58A132ED0008B979-D                                                                                        29D1700
To: <sip:17818100188@xx.xx.xx.xx:5060>;tag=as6ad8c2be
Call-ID: 16-471011CE-58A132ED0008BA04-D29D1700
CSeq: 10 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 13.10.0
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLIS                                                                                        H, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
Contact: <sip:17818100188@xx.xx.xx.xx:5060>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 269

v=0
o=root 876537524 876537524 IN IP4 xx.xx.xx.xx
s=Asterisk PBX 13.10.0
c=IN IP4 xx.xx.xx.xx
t=0 0
m=audio 17380 RTP/AVP 18 0 8
a=rtpmap:18 G729/8000
a=fmtp:18 annexb=no
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=ptime:20
a=maxptime:150
a=sendrecv

<------------>

<--- SIP read from UDP:46.19.209.14:5060 --->
ACK sip:17818100188@xx.xx.xx.xx:5060 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 46.19.209.14;branch=z9hG4bKtk4jVaWe;rport
From: 16173730982 <sip:16173730982@46.19.209.14>;tag=3B8DECC2-58A132ED0008B979-D                                                                                        29D1700
To: <sip:17818100188@xx.xx.xx.xx:5060>;tag=as6ad8c2be
CSeq: 10 ACK
Call-ID: 16-471011CE-58A132ED0008BA04-D29D1700
Contact: <sip:46.19.209.14:5060>
Max-Forwards: 70
Content-Length: 0

<------------->


-- <SIP/46.19.209.14-0000023b> Playing '/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/es/enter_PI                                                                                        N.slin' (language 'es')
Sent RTP packet to      46.19.209.79:51054 (type 18, seq 027986, ts 000320, len                                                                                         000020)
Sent RTP packet to      46.19.209.79:51054 (type 18, seq 027987, ts 000480, len                                                                                         000020)
Sent RTP packet to      46.19.209.79:51054 (type 18, seq 027988, ts 000640, len                                                                                         000020)
Sent RTP packet to      46.19.209.79:51054 (type 18, seq 027989, ts 000800, len                                                                                         000020)
Sent RTP packet to      46.19.209.79:51054 (type 18, seq 027990, ts 000960, len                                                                                         000020)
Sent RTP packet to      46.19.209.79:51054 (type 18, seq 027991, ts 001120, len                                                                                         000020)
   > 0x7fb8f0019460 -- Probation passed - setting RTP source address to 46.1                                                                                        9.209.79:51054
Got  RTP packet from    46.19.209.79:51054 (type 18, seq 021627, ts 2308319632,                                                                                         len 000020)
Sent RTP packet to      46.19.209.79:51054 (type 18, seq 027992, ts 001280, len                                                                                         000020)
Got  RTP packet from    46.19.209.79:51054 (type 18, seq 021628, ts 2308319792,                                                                                         len 000020)
Sent RTP packet to      46.19.209.79:51054 (type 18, seq 027993, ts 001440, len                                                                                         000020)
Got  RTP packet from    46.19.209.79:51054 (type 18, seq 021629, ts 2308319952,                                                                                         len 000020)
Sent RTP packet to      46.19.209.79:51054 (type 18, seq 027994, ts 001600, len                                                                                         000020)
Got  RTP packet from    46.19.209.79:51054 (type 18, seq 021630, ts 2308320112,                                                                                         len 000020)
Sent RTP packet to      46.19.209.79:51054 (type 18, seq 027995, ts 001760, len                                                                                         000020)
Got  RTP packet from    46.19.209.79:51054 (type 18, seq 021631, ts 2308320272,                                                                                         len 000020)
Sent RTP packet to      46.19.209.79:51054 (type 18, seq 027996, ts 001920, len                                                                                         000020)
Got  RTP packet from    46.19.209.79:51054 (type 18, seq 021632, ts 2308320432,                                                                                         len 000020)
Sent RTP packet to      46.19.209.79:51054 (type 18, seq 027997, ts 002080, len                                                                                         000020)
Got  RTP packet from    46.19.209.79:51054 (type 18, seq 021633, ts 2308320592,                                                                                         len 000020)
Sent RTP packet to      46.19.209.79:51054 (type 18, seq 027998, ts 002240, len                                                                                         000020)
Got  RTP packet from    46.19.209.79:51054 (type 18, seq 021634, ts 2308320752,                                                                                         len 000020)
Sent RTP packet to      46.19.209.79:51054 (type 18, seq 027999, ts 002400, len                                                                                         000020)
Got  RTP packet from    46.19.209.79:51054 (type 18, seq 021635, ts 2308320912,                                                                                         len 000020)
Sent RTP packet to      46.19.209.79:51054 (type 18, seq 028000, ts 002560, len                                                                                         000020)
Got  RTP packet from    46.19.209.79:51054 (type 18, seq 021636, ts 2308321072,                                                                                         len 000020)
Sent RTP packet to      46.19.209.79:51054 (type 18, seq 028001, ts 002720, len                                                                                         000020)
```

Comment: What does your DTMF log show you?

Comment: Where can I see DTMF log?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to switch to SIP INFO dtmf mode (set this both on your SIP client and in Asterisk "dtmfmode").

Then you will be able to see the DTMF messages clearly in the SIP signaling.

Comment: How do I set SIP INFO dtmf mode. I have tried sip set dtmf on but didnt work

Comment: @adediranoladapo `dtmfmode=info` in `sip.conf`.